# How to capture TCP/IP packets with standard user

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming

I would like to write a program to capture TCP packets from a particular IP address coming to my system. I can't use Wireshark or tcpdump for this as these tools require root/sudo previleges even api(s) like *libpcap* require root previlege.

Is there any other way to capture TCP packets without root previlege? I would prefer programs instead of tools. I don't wanna make changes in kernel code.

Comment: Is somebody trying to snoop at college?

Comment: It's not like that. I want this to be done for some research work.

Comment: If you have a valid reason then you should be able to gain root access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any other way to capture TCP packets without root previlege?

I really, really hope not. That would be a pretty massive security hole.

You could install a network 'tap' device into the LAN wiring and then run Wireshark on a separate computer to which you do have root access. But of course that requires physical access to the server...